How to Position Icon Above Text in QPushButton in PyQt6
I have a QPushButton with an Icon. By default the Icon is placed to the left of the button text like this:

Using a QToolButton I can achieve the desired behavior with: button.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonStyle.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
is there a similar straightforward approach to do this for a QPushButton?

No, there isn't. While you could attempt to use the button as a container with its own layout, adding a widget for the icon (possibly using QLabel or a custom QWidget displaying the QIcon) and the label as an actual QLabel, the effort would be quite huge (and unreliable) considering the possible related issues, such as styling problems, proper layout management, icon size and display, etc. What is your reason for avoiding QToolButton? It seems like you're having an XY problem.

My hesitation from using a QToolButton is that its supposed to be used for tool bars, and I want to add this button to my main layout. Additionally, I want my button to appear flat and Tool Button doesn't have the method .setFlat() However, if using a ToolButton in my main GUI doesn't cause any problems? I will just use that. Thanks!

From docs: "It is also possible to construct tool buttons in the same way as any other widget, and arrange them alongside other widgets in layouts."

QToolButton has setAutoRaise as an alternative to setFlat. Despite the name, this widget wasn't designed only for use with tool-bars - it has many other common uses apart from that (e.g. in combination with a line-edit for selecting files). That's why it's called a tool-button, rather than a toolbar-button.

You can use QToolButton, it work's. in QToolButton you can set icon position.
self.my_button = QToolButton(self)
self.my_button.setText("Hello!")
self.my_button.move(10, 10)
self.my_button.setIcon(QIcon("my_icon.png"))
self.my_button.setFixedSize(40, 40)
self.my_button.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonStyle.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)

